# Как отправить данные через USB?

Tags: c++, windows, arduino, usb, libusb

Я хочу отправить данные через USB на Arduino. Сам микроконтроллер запрограммирован ждать сигнал с serial-порта. Я пытаюсь сделать это при помощи libusb, но что-то не работает, хотя компилируется без ошибок. Подскажите пожалуйста, может я пропустила какой-то необходимый шаг?

edit: На плате есть микросхема CH340G – преобразователь интерфейса USB в UART.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "libusb.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int r;

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;


    libusb_device_handle* dev_handle;

    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, 6790, 29987);

    unsigned char data = 1;
    int act_length;

    unsigned char endpoint = (0x02 | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT);

    libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0x00);

    libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, endpoint, &data, sizeof(data), &act_length, 15);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На плате есть микросхема CH340G – преобразователь интерфейса USB в UART. То есть получается, этот конвертер есть на самой Arduino

Comment: Да, точно. Тогда мне стоит использовать библиотеки для соединения с COM-портом?

Comment: В общем, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываете виртуальный COM-порт как терминал и пишете в него команды.